# How do i access an object's key but i want to pass the key as a variable

Tags: javascript, key, javascript-objects

for example:

```
object = {
  name: "Mike",
  age: 15
}

object.age // returns 15 right?
```

But I want to pass the 'age' key as a variable name:

```
object = {
  name: "Mike",
  age: 15
}

const age = 10.toString()
```

How do I get the result of something like this:

```
object.`${age}`
```

Comment: `object[age]`, but `10.toString()` is syntactically invalid, and it's uncertain, why you'd want the string `'10'` to begin with. Don't you want `'age'`?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
object["age"]
```

or

```
var propName='age'
object[propName]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by

```js
object[age]
```

Answer (score 0):

Properties can be accessed by either `.` (dot notation) or via brackets `[]`
that is:

```
object[key_name]
// where key_name is a variable
object["some_key"] // {"some_key":"value"} or {some_value:"value"}
object[19] // {19:"some_value"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) like;

```js
var object = { name: "Mike"
             , age : 15
             },
    {age}  = object;

console.log(age);
```